# How to display a background behind ad only when adblock is enabled?

Tags: javascript, css, adblock

Im trying to display a background image where usually a 300x250 ad would be, but only when adblock is blocking the ad. Anyone know how this can be done? Using a div causes the background to show before the ad loads which I do not want.

Thanks

Comment: what does it have to do with php ?

Answer (score 1):

Since adblock software is installed on the visitor's computer, there is no way to know if an ad is blocked (that I can think of). But, since ads are displayed with JavaScript - which is targeted and blocked specifically by the adblock software - you might be able to write some JavaScript that checks whether the ads were loaded at the end of the page, and if not, add a CSS class to your `div` showing the background image you want. Pseudo code:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .adblocked { background: url("img/no-ad.jpg") left top no-repeat; }
</style>

<div id="ad"></div>

<script src="ads.js"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof adLibraryName === "undefined") {
        // ad stuff was not loaded
        document.getElementById("ad").className += " adblocked";
    }
</script>
```

This, as MAXIM stated, has nothing to do with PHP and there is no way that you can get it to work with PHP, because PHP runs on the server and does not know if ad blocking is installed. Simply put, all of this is a client side problem.

Comment: +1; Check via JS whether the ad was loaded and insert a CSS class is a good solution. You could also check whether a specific element was created or if a file could be loaded from some ad-server. Similar techniques are used on some websites to display a "Please disable AdBlock"-Banner. Also, `elem.classList.add("adblocked");` would work in modern browsers; see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

Answer (score 0):

To check if Adsense is being blocked, and therefore load alternate content into the ad containers.

if (typeof(window.google_jobrunner) == 'undefined') {

// Adsense is being blocked, load something else into the containers

}

It's a good idea to set the height of the containers with CSS if doing this.

You can check what Adblock Plus is blocking in Firefox, by selecting 'Open blockable items'.

Adblock Plus also blocks images with common ad dimensions in the filenames, eg 'whatever_468x60.png' will probably get blocked.

Answer (score -1):

since you tagged your question with PHP I'll answer with php glasses on: 
The problem with this is that adblocking is client-side, adding a div via php is server side. So you would first have to know what happens on the client-side ans THEN compose your code -  but that won't work. You could probably still do this through an AJAX request – but that would mean you would first send out the page without knowing if adblock is activated anyways…

cheers, ±…

Comment: well - thänx for rating my 'answer' - doesn't really help anybody nor motivate me - but thänx anyways… As I mentioned above the question was first tagged as a PHP-question and so I tried to give it a PHP-answer…… Whatever.

Comment: There is no useful PHP answer to that question. If you're not sure, what the question meant, try to ask for that in a comment first.